# Azure DevOps rate limit warnings

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps REST API to periodically retrieve new Git commits, branches, and PRs within my organization. I've created my own Azure Connected Application, and using OAuth tokens for authentication. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) is one example of the requests I'm making.

This all works fine, but from time to time I'm getting email messages from Azure DevOps saying the API usage is exceeding their limits. These messages are being sent to the account that I used to connect the Azure Application. The contents of these messages is usually the following:

```
User Agent: RestSharp/106.5.0.0
Time Range: 9/10/2021 4:15 AM - 4:20 AM
Service: TFS (https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization-PROD/)
Application: Git
Command: GitCommits.GetCommits
Status: Normal
Count: 247
Usage: 140.158
Delay: 0.000
```

I've had a look at the [Azure Rate Limiting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops), which suggest that my application is supposed to be receiving headers like `X-RateLimit-...` or `Retry-After` when approaching the limits. However, I have inspected all my request logs over the last couple of months and found no headers like this in any of the responses.

This raises some questions:

1. Why am I getting these email warnings, if there are no rate limit headers in the responses? Are these warnings even connected to the rate limiting described in the Azure docs mentioned above?
2. Is there any way to turn off these email notifications?
3. Since most of the warnings contain the `Command: GitCommits.GetCommits` part, does this mean that only my `GetCommit` requests are too frequent, but the branch and PR related requests are not? Are these rate limits per-resource?